# what regex finds all words of length 6 or more in a string

Tags: java, regex

My regex has to parse all words which are longer than 6 symbols in multiline string.

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w{7,}\\s\\b.*)");

        Matcher mm = pattern.matcher(lines);

        if (mm.matches()) {

            String oldGroup = mm.group();
```

________Here is example input:

```
1234567 1234567 1234567
1234 123 1234567
123 12345 1234 1234567
123
```

_______And here is expected ouput:

```
1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567
```

So, i just need that only words with 6 or more letter symbols to be outputted.

Comment: Read it three times and I still don't understand what you want. Show us some examples... Of input **and** expected output.

Comment: Thanks, linked thread gave me some clue.

Comment: So is your question just "what regex finds all words of length 6 or more in a string"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, at first i was searching for complex method of writing sorted words to the file using appropriate regex, but then the task became more clear and narrow, so thanks for the tip, maybe i should rather rename the question than mislead somebody else)

Comment: regexp isn't the multitool that solves all problems. If you need to process string data for things like sorting, use normal string splitting and collection filtering/sorting/etc.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, completely agreed! Finally, solution of the same task with simple for- cycle took nearly the same space and seemed at least so much convincing as solution with regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\b\S{7,}\b)/

1st Capturing group (\b\S{7,}\b)
    \b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
    \S{7,} match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
        Quantifier: {7,} Between 7 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```